# A way to remove the appended url from the url parameter in $.ajax for jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, post

I am using cakephp and want to use the `jQuery.ajax` to post to my server. The issue is jQuery's `$.ajax` appends the protocol and hostname, but also includes the current controller, so I cannot change the controller I am pasting too.

Is there a way to change the url: parameter in `$.ajax`? Here is my sample post code:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'controller/action',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you looking for $.post or $.ajax? In your question you write $.post but your sample code uses $.ajax

Comment: Can't you define the url in an external variable and call that instead; `var url = 'http://foo/bar'` and then `$.post(url, data, callback)` ?

Comment: let me try that quick, and yes my bad @kannix, Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file lets suppose 'site_constants.php' containing some constant variables in app/Config folder. Define the following constants into it:

```
<?php    
define('HTTP_HOST', "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
if(HTTP_HOST == 'localhost' || HTTP_HOST == '127.0.0.1')
{
     define('SITE_URL', HTTP_HOST.'app_folder_name/');
}
else
{
     define('SITE_URL', HTTP_HOST);
}
```

Include it in `app/Config/bootstrap.php`

```
require_once('site_constants.php');
```

Define JS variable constant into your main layout file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var SITE_URL = '<?php echo SITE_URL?>';
</script>
```

Now you can use it anywhere into your website. And this is also a dynamic, you don't need to change the url in every ajax method.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: SITE_URL+'controller/action',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

**This might looks long process to handle this task, but once done, it will help you in many senses.**

Here are the advantages:

1. you can easily define some more constants (like any file path etc).
2. you can put all your ajax code into external JS files.
3. you can directly deploy it onto any server without changing in constants as well as work perfectly onto your localhost.
4. following standard conventions etc.

Comment: Awesome Idea. I was trying to do the same. Thanks @Arun

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/controller/action',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

You see the difference? If you put "/" (slash) in front of the URL it will be appended to your domain name, if it is without it will be appended on your current URL.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the exact/more specific URL you want to post to in the URL section of the `$.post` setup...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://host/controller/action',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In cakePHP, you could do:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>controller/action',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
```

if your ajax code is in js file then you could do:
in your **layouts/default.ctp** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var webroot = "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>";
</script>
```

then in your js file that contains ajax, you can use js variable **webroot**:

```
$.ajax({
      url: webroot + 'controller/action',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
          console.log(json);
      }
});
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: How's that ever gonna work if the `js` code was not inline & loaded from some external `.js` file?