# cakephp ajax remote function select input parameter

Tags: ajax, cakephp, parameters

I try to do two inputs in cakePHP (category, subcategory).
And if i change category input i want ajax to load values to subcategories.
What i can do it?
Im using remote function like this:

```
$ajax->remoteFunction( 
        array( 
            'url' => array( 'controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'loadSubcategories', AND NOW I WANT PUT HERE CATEGORY ID FROM MY INPUT ), 
            'update' => 'subcategories' 
        )
); 

<select name="categories" id="categories" onhange="MY REMOTE FUNCTION">
CATEGORIES
</select>

<select name="subcategories" id="categories" onhange="MY REMOTE FUNCTION">
LOAD SUBCATEGORIES BY CATEGORY ID WITH AJAX
</select>
```

I hope you can understand me :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

1. a Cake action that outputs a list of items based on the data it receives (shouldn't be hard)
2. a bit of JS that figures out which categories are selected (which you already have)
3. another bit of JS that packages that data and sends it to the Cake action
4. another bit of JS that updates the site with the list of items you received back

I'd take a look at [jQuery's AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to accomplish this task. If you POST the data in a format like this, it's very easily accessible in `$this->data` in Cake:

```
{
    'data[ModelName][categories]' : $("#category").val()
}
```

Comment: ok, im understand you, but it can`t be done by ajax helper?
I know jquery, and i can use it, but i must type basehref to app in my post jquery function.

For ex when i have website on http://localhost/myapp/controller/action/parameter
And type in post action 'controler/action' then Jquery send post to localhost/controller/action and lost the myapp folder...

Comment: This also not a big issue. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211528/a-way-to-remove-the-appended-url-from-the-url-parameter-in-ajax-for-jquery/12212509#12212509